# Symfony - error because of addslashes in DQL query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql, addslashes

I do:

```
    $text = '%'.addslashes($text).'%';


    $images = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT img, cat, u
                       FROM AcmeMainBundle:Image img
                       JOIN img.category cat
                       JOIN img.user u
                       WHERE img.title LIKE '$text' OR img.description LIKE '$text'
                       ORDER BY img.id DESC")
        ->getResult();
```

and when $text contains some ' than it throws error

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 150: Error: Expected end of string, got 'T'
>   500 Internal Server Error - QueryException

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

```php
   $images = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery("SELECT img, cat, u
                       FROM AcmeMainBundle:Image img
                       JOIN img.category cat
                       JOIN img.user u
                       WHERE img.title LIKE :text OR img.description LIKE :text
                       ORDER BY img.id DESC")
        ->setParameter('text', $text)
        ->getResult();
```

Or try this:

```php
   $text = "%".$text."%";
   $images = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()
        ->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select(array('img','cat','u'))
        ->from('AcmeMainBundle:Image', 'img')
        ->innerJoin('img.category', 'cat')
        ->innerJoin('img.user', 'u')
        ->where('img.title LIKE :title OR img.description LIKE :description')
        ->orderBy('img.id','DESC')
        ->setParameter('title', $title)
        ->setParameter('description', $title)
        ->getResult();
```

Comment: what does it change? I've tried it before, but i don't remember if i used ':text' or just :text. BTW. now i create whole WHERE part before query and i do just "... WHERE $search" and i also tried "... WHERE :search" but it changes nothing.

Comment: Oh… I forget that percentages. You have to use it like in PDO – `$text = "%".$text."%";`

Comment: do you mean to remove "addslashes(...)"? see above on my code.

Comment: Yes, you don't need it. Doctrine uses to escape PDO.

Comment: It still doesn't work. Read my first comment under this answer.